# I am developing an android app with multiple users. How to mantain session each time different user logged into the system?

Tags: android, android-studio, session-management

2 types of users in one app (let's say, admin and client). Would like to make session management like in PHP. How can I do that in the android app?

2 users as clients logged into the app, so are there any ways to maintain session for these users?

Comment: SharedPrefrences

Comment: @behrad can shared preferences save data for different users if I want to run the app say, on emulator?

Comment: For example; 2 users as clients logged in.

Comment: Don't exactly use `SharedPreference` as the data is saved in Plain Text, use `DataStore` or `EncryptedSharedPreferences` or `EncryptedFile`. And Yes, you can save multiple session data against the unique user ids.